# Saving base64 image greater than 1MB to SQL Server, the image is corrupted

Tags: c#, sql-server, image-uploading

I am trying to upload images from an IOS app created in Xamarin forms, the issue is when the file is greater that 1 MB the image cannot be retrieved from the DB, the error message is the file is corrupted.
I am using an API to save the image to the database (using Dapper) the code below shows the saving of the base64 string. The data field is set to nvarchar(max) which I think that 2 MB should not be too large.

```
byte[] fileData = null;
var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[i];
Image picIn = Image.FromStream(pic.InputStream);
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(pic.InputStream))
{
    fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(pic.ContentLength);
}
var file = new UploadedFilesBase64()
{
    FileName = newFileName, // String Containing File Name
    UploadedFile = Convert.ToBase64String(fileData) // The Base64 String
};
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    cn.Insert(file);
}
```

Everything works fine if the file size is less than 1 MB, we do upload files that can reach 2 MB

Any help on finding a solution would be great

Comment: No need to convert image to base64. Use `VARBINARY(max)` and upload binary data.

Comment: The same thing happens with VARBINARY(Max), we are using Sql Server 2014, I have tried several options, all the same.

Comment: The database isn't going to say "the file is corrupted", it doesn't care what's in your columns. Check what's actually in the table (`DATALENGTH`) and how it gets *retrieved*. You're assuming the code that *stores* is the problem. If you *are* getting the error message in this exact piece of code, then your web server or HTTP connection is the problem, not your SQL Server.

Comment: Use `UPDATE` or `INSERT` in SQL for `VARBINARY(max)` column. From C# side send `byte[]` object as `SqlCommand` parameter of type `SqlDbType.Image`. It works. PS: What is `UploadedFilesBase64`?

Comment: Thanks Guys, I have been going through the code line by line and checking the actual image at every stage, the file is captured 'var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[i];' and it is good, then read from the stream 'Image picIn = Image.FromStream(pic.InputStream);' and still the image is good, the next line is where the problem persist, 'fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(pic.ContentLength);' at this point I tried to decode it and the image is corrupted, I have eliminated SQL from the issue, this is purely a c# problem I am using VS 2017 Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a lot of testing and with the ideas from @i486 and @JeroenMostert the issue is even that the function exist in c# `fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(pic.ContentLength);`
the proper way to do it to achieve success is like this

```
Encoder myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    picIn.Save(memoryStream, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
    fileData = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

This solved the problem and now it works

Comment: Except that this code needlessly degrades the image by re-saving it as horribly low quality jpg. Your _real_ problem is trying to read from the same stream twice. You should just save the bytes from the stream into a byte array, and _then_ make the image from the bytes, not the other way around.

Comment: @Nyerguds I understand what you are saying, the images seem to be clear when read and displayed, the idea was to have the images saved. I know there is a better way, but this was a time sensitive issue as we could not upload images as they would not be legible. I will definitely work on your suggestion for our next release. Thank you.